# right side div not filling up right side

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website for my company.  I have a div on the right that is gray that extends down to the bottom.  It works on every page except this one.  I cannot figure out why it won't extend down to the footer.  I have created a jsfiddle for it.  If you inspect the divs in the fiddle, you will notice that .leftSide, .mainWrap, and .paddingWrap are not extending down past the "Brochures" title at the top.  I can tell this because when I hover over each those divs in the html, the blue and purple only covers the "Brochures" title.  I think that is what is tricking .rightSide into not extending down where it should go.  I have tried my best to remove all the code in the fiddle that is not relevant to my question.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyzhZ/)

Relavant CSS:

```
section.rightSide
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 900px;
    /*float: right;*/
    width: 238px;
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
    padding: 15px 5px 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.leftSide 
{
    padding-right: 248px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.paddingWrap
{
    padding: 15px 70px;
}

section.mainWrap
{    
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: probably because that page is higher than the min-height of 900px, and the content wrapper is less tall. The `top:0; bottom: 0` trick does work how you'd expect, but as the parent div is not tall as tall as the page itself, the result isn't as expected

Comment: OK, well this code works on every other page(10+ pages).  Something about this specific page is stopping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to put this in your CSS: -

```
.main-content {
     overflow: hidden;   
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gyzhZ/2/

Comment: Hmmm, well, that fixed that specific page, but it broke most of my other pages.  The gray rightside no longer extends down anymore on the other pages.  Weird!

Comment: I guess that will be because your brochures content (or equivalent) is not as long on other pages as on this page. You could possibly just put this fix on just the one page. Or for a more sturdy way to do full height divs you could look at using a css display: table layout approx (e.g. http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout)

Comment: Sorry, approach not approx!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will look into one of those options.  I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Here is a template fiddle to get you started: - http://jsfiddle.net/DY56Y/2/